# Advice for internal grant application write up

Tags: application, funding, peer-review

I am writing an internal grant proposal (as a new faculty recruits). The university has asked for the names of at least three external experts as application reviewers. The university review panel (mostly non-experts) will take experts' comments under consideration, then match the application against the university's criteria to come to a final decision. My question is :

- How many technicalities can I put into the application? Can I put in equations and preliminary results? As I have learned it is advisable to put technical info (esp. jargon) in the grant applications. But given that experts may (or may not) review the, can I get suggestions.
- Of course, I do not have the final results yet, the idea is half-baked in my mind (which I am putting on the paper). It may evolve when I do the actual research on the project. How can I approach this in my application? Also, how can I convince the reviewer that I am looking for genuine work and not proposing a gimmick to get the funds

PS. This is my first application as a faculty member, I did write funding applications during my Ph.D., but they were not successful.

Answer (score 1):

You could write two sections in the narrative, one not so technical and one technical. The local committee will appreciate the former, the external experts the latter.